# Why does this while loop using a data frame attribute not work?

Tags: python, while-loop

While I'm still learning Python, I'm just baffled by this one.  This while loop gets the error:
"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'empty'" and I cannot figure out why.  Your help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tickData = pd.DataFrame([])

print (tickData.empty)

while tickData.empty:
  tickData
  tickData = [1,2,3]
  print (tickData)
  
print (tickData)
```

Comment: You are changing `tickData` from a dataframe to a list with `tickData=[1,2,3]`, which doesn't support `.empty`

Comment: you redefine tickData with every iteration and your list doesn't have an `.empty` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you had given `tickData` as a Dataframe and later on, you are changing that to a list datatype which is not having any attribute `empty`. The while loop is based upon the condition `tickData.empty` and hence it throws the attribute error.

Hope this helps.